# Display Entries done in database asynchronously in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, asynchronous

I have a made a customized log functionality for my web application(ASP.NET , C#.NET) which adds entries based on user actions to the database.

I want to display the Entries - with the most current one first asynchronously , without the page refreshing , just like a rss feed or data feed is loaded as new entries are added.

What are my options to implement it in asp.net , c# in visual studio?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use ajax long polling using services or SignalR concept.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @watraplion!! Can you direct me to any tutorials or basic introduction of the concepts/? would really appreciate that!! thnx

Comment: Refer this : http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/315574-How-refresh-gridview-every-3seconds-by-using-code-dotnet.aspx